# App to transfer the files by shaking the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

Is there any iPhone app that allows me to transfer music to another iPhone by shaking the iPhone nearby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bu.mp/ does the job.

Simply get the app on both iPhones, open the apps and "bump" them together to share the files.

Comment: to me that's a "lol" app!